# Should we migrate too stackoverflowish questions to stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, migration, stackoverflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get a "Belongs on StackOverflow" as a closing reason?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/can-we-get-a-belongs-on-stackoverflow-as-a-closing-reason)

suggestions, please!

Comment: Related discussion: [Should we have a “not subjective enough” close reason?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/14/should-we-have-a-not-subjective-enough-close-reason)

Comment: Do you mean migrating subjective questions from StackOverflow or objective ones to it?

Comment: @Simon Brown: too objective for us and appropriate for they, of course.

Comment: And what about the reverse?  Migrating questions from SO to us?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that it was asked in its own question...

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, if most of the users on programmers are also on SO, AND if Jeff&co. are ok, there would be no problem in migrating questions to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I would really like this, along with all the questions being reopened. This way discussion that was halted because of the close could restart, and new answers could flow in for the single "Don't ask here, ask (obscure site)" type answer to the question.

I see two issues though

- **The amount of questions that could be moved is immense**. I haven't done any statistics, but I put it in the hundreds
- **What about old questions?** Moving a question asked and closed in 08 and reopening here would make little sense.
- **Moving by batch processes would get false positives.**

Comment: I think he was talking about the opposite, migrating questions from programmers to stackoverflow

Comment: and moreover, it would be nice to have some community based and programmatically supported mechanism to migrate questions across the whole SO sites family.

Comment: @Max: you mean the **SE** sites family, don't you?

Comment: @Lorenzo: As you wish:)