# Can we get a "Belongs on StackOverflow" as a closing reason?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, migration

Once in a while someone pops up with an objective "help me with my code" question like [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/pyton-gtk-menu-show-the-menu-at-a-certain-position). I think it'd be nice to have a mechanism to migrate these to StackOverflow. Thoughts?

Comment: Related: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/new-question-migration-paths/ probably we don't get it because we are beta or the algorithm needs refinement.

Comment: I agree with Anna, a lot of questions belong on stackoverflow or have already been asked and answered there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that the site is no longer in beta, there is a direct migration path to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8):

Not until the site leaves beta, and then we'll have to provide evidence of open questions that should be migrated and closed questions that should have been migrated.

To that end - if anyone comes across a question that fits the bill, edit it into this answer so we don't have to do it all at once.

### Stack Overflow

- [Pyton + GTK.Menu - show the menu at a certain position [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/pyton-gtk-menu-show-the-menu-at-a-certain-position-closed)
- [jQuery $.Post quirk [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11451/jquery-post-quirk)
- [mod_security + apache + geoip block != 404](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12942/mod-security-apache-geoip-block-404)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12566/how-to-name-a-single-purpose-class-and-method-closed
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12426/what-methods-can-be-employed-for-using-composition-over-inheritance-closed
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12271/how-i-do-versioning-for-an-web-application-closed
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225848/transform-class-text-to-my-domain-name-without-http-and-www

### Server Fault

- [In NameBench results, what is TO and other questions? [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11723/in-namebench-results-what-is-to-and-other-questions-closed)

### Super User

- [How is Linux not prone to viruses or that kind? [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9141/how-is-linux-not-prone-to-viruses-or-that-kind)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12839/what-monitors-have-larger-than-hd-resolution-size-is-less-important-closed
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12584/how-would-you-make-a-qwerty-keyboard-more-programming-friendly-closed
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12565/best-out-of-box-linux-distro-for-general-programming-closed
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12375/what-mouse-model-or-brand-do-you-like-closed
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11895/recommendation-electronic-reader-closed
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11577/running-javascript-on-the-command-line-closed

Comment: Cool. Thanks, Chris.

Comment: Isn't that "Inherit an Interface" question a subjective sort of programmer terminology question?  At least I believe it was asked in that vein.  If it doesn't belong you might as well add the "Proper Pronounciation of Delphi" and "SQL" questions to your list.

Comment: @Peter - not "my" list but "our" list. If you disagree edit it out.