# Can we get new migration paths setup?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get a “Belongs on StackOverflow” as a closing reason?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/can-we-get-a-belongs-on-stackoverflow-as-a-closing-reason)

According to the [new blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/new-question-migration-paths/), we can now move questions in between sites. Would it be possible for us, even though were in beta, to have several migration paths setup?

Sites that I think deserve a migration path:

- Stackoverflow

  - Objective questions are already being asked here and will just grow.
  - Examples

    - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12566/how-to-name-a-single-purpose-class-and-method-closed
    - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12426/what-methods-can-be-employed-for-using-composition-over-inheritance-closed
    - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12271/how-i-do-versioning-for-an-web-application-closed
    - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/pyton-gtk-menu-show-the-menu-at-a-certain-position-closed
    - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11451/jquery-post-quirk-closed
- SuperUser

  - Originally there were few good questions about computer setups which resulted in many objective questions about setups. We really don't need this stuff here
  - Examples

    - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12839/what-monitors-have-larger-than-hd-resolution-size-is-less-important-closed
    - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12584/how-would-you-make-a-qwerty-keyboard-more-programming-friendly-closed
    - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12565/best-out-of-box-linux-distro-for-general-programming-closed
    - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12375/what-mouse-model-or-brand-do-you-like-closed
    - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11895/recommendation-electronic-reader-closed
    - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11577/running-javascript-on-the-command-line-closed

Think this can be setup? It would make much of this site a bit more friendly instead of a straight close.

Comment: Please add your examples to my CW answer to the linked question

Answer (score 1):

The current philosophy from the Team is that they [won't provide migration until the Beta is over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68000/allow-beta-sites-to-migrate-questions-to-relevant-sites/68003#68003), but it seems like that part of the site should be vetted in Beta also.

Comment: I was hoping to change that here

Comment: @TheLQ, I hope you can, I threw you a vote to help out.